# Can't find the mistake in this attempt to find expected max of two exponential random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

We have that $X,Y$ are independent exponential random variables with rates $\mu,\lambda$ respectively. We're to find $E(\mathrm{max}\{X,Y\})$. I'm getting the wrong answer and I don't know why.

I have seen alternate proofs arriving at the correct answer---my question is not how to solve this problem, my question is what is wrong with the below reasoning.

\begin{align}
E(\mathrm{max}\{X,Y\})&=E(X|Y<X)P(Y<X) + E(Y|X<Y)P(X<Y)\\
&= E(X)P(Y<X) + E(Y)P(X<Y)\\
&= \frac1\mu P(Y<X) + \frac1\lambda P(X<Y)\\
&= \frac 1\mu \cdot \frac \lambda{\lambda+\mu} + \frac1\lambda\cdot  \frac \mu{\lambda+\mu}\\
&=\frac{\mu^2+\lambda^2}{\mu\lambda(\mu+\lambda)}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you include the answer you ere expecting?

Comment: @IanMiller $$\frac{1}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{\mu}-\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}= \frac{\mu^2+\mu\lambda+\lambda^2}{\mu\lambda(\lambda+\mu)}.$$

Comment: @ClementC That is to say: $\mathsf E(\max\{X,Y\}) ~=~ \mathsf E(X+Y-\min\{X,Y\})$ which requires having obtained $\mathsf E(\min\{X,Y\})$ earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mistake is that you do not have
$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y < X] = \mathbb{E}[X].
$$
First, note that *a priori*, the left-hand side is a conditional expectation, i.e. a random variable, while the right-hand side is a real value (a "number"). So the "type" of the objects is not straightforwardly even compatible.

You would have equality *if* $X$ were independent of $\mathbb{1}_{\{X>Y\}}$, but this is not obvious this is the case (and actually it's not). $X$ is independent of $Y$, sure; but not of $\mathbb{1}_{\{X>Y\}}$.